# Volume Weighted Moving Averages

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas

I have a DataFrame that looks like:

```
              LAST PRICE        VOLUME     volume_ratio
date                                                             
2005-01-03      1202.08     1.332210e+09       1.23       
2005-01-04      1188.05     1.552646e+09       1.55       
2005-01-05      1183.74     1.428365e+09       1.65         
2005-01-06      1187.89     1.331004e+09       1.23         
2005-01-07      1186.19     1.273960e+09       0.83        
2005-01-10      1190.25     1.213694e+09       1.06
```

With a `period = 5`, I want to compute a moving average `VAMA = CumSum/CumDiv` where `CumSum = (df['volume_ratio']*df['LAST PRICE']).cumsum()` and `CumDiv = df['volume_ratio'].cumsum()`, with the condition `CumDiv <= Period`.

Initially I thought using `expanding.sum()` and `df.apply` would work but I am struggling with it; something like:

```
cum_div = df['volume_ratio'].expanding(min_periods = 1).sum()
cum_summ = (df['LAST PRICE']*df['volume_ratio']).expanding(min_periods                =1).sum()

df['cum_sum'] = df.apply(lambda x: cum_summ if cum_div <= 13, axis = 1)
```

This clearly doesn't work, so I was interested in the best way to attack this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have outputs to validate against?

Answer (score 2):

just using `rolling` http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html

```
df['myrollingmean'] = df.VAMA.rolling(window = 5).mean()
```